# How to skip first line from reading and sorting C#

Tags: c#

I have this code for sorting a csv file. How to skip first line of file from reading and sorting because se first line has the names of columns. the file looks like:

```
ID Name Surname Age Salary
1  John Asben   33  1000
2  Adam Smith   22  1200
```

The code is:

```
private void buttonSortSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sorted =
      File.ReadLines(@"C:\....dat.csv")
        .Select(line => new
        {
            SortKey = Int32.Parse(line.Split(',')[3]),
            Line = line
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.SortKey)
        .Select(x => x.Line);
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\sorteddata.csv", sorted);
}
```

Comment: Use [`Skip(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx)

Comment: There's no need for the `Select().OrderBy().Select()` that you have.  The `OrderBy` method takes a selector.  Use that to get the appropriate value to sort on.  You can then remove the other two `Select` methods.

Answer (score 8):

```
File.ReadLines(@"C:\....dat.csv")
.Skip(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Raphaël's solution, you can use a Memoize function to keep the header row but sort the rest. Microsoft's Ix-Main nuget package has it among other very useful extensions, or you can just use ReadAllLines() or ToArray():

```
var items = File.ReadLines(@"C:\....dat.csv").Memoize(2);

var sorted = items.Take(1)
    .Concat(items.Skip(1).OrderBy(line => Int32.Parse(line.Split(',')[3])));

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\sorteddata.csv", sorted);
```

Comment: The OS is going to cache that page of file anyway, so you could do that without memoizing it and it's unlikely that you'd see any problems.  Note that using `ReadAllLines` or `ToArray` could easily cause problems if the file is of non-trivially small size.

Comment: `OrderBy` has the storage overhead of `ToArray` internally, so while an additional `ToArray` will definitely increase memory usage it probably won't be that bad unless it's a huge file. Keep in mind the strings aren't copied so it won't be a 100% overhead. `Memoize` will remove all that extra overhead, though, and still not need to read the file twice, which is why I suggest it over `ToArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Use file helpers:

```
FileHelpers.CsvOptions options = new FileHelpers.CsvOptions("ImportRecord", ',', file);
options.HeaderLines = 0;        

FileHelpers.CsvEngine engine = new FileHelpers.CsvEngine(options);
//read header
engine.Options.IgnoreFirstLines = 0; 
DataTable header = engine.ReadStringAsDT(FileHelpers.CommonEngine.RawReadFirstLines(file, 1)); 
//read the rest of the data without the header
engine.Options.IgnoreFirstLines = 1;
DataTable data = engine.ReadFileAsDT(file);
```